# checking for conditions inside <xsl:value-of>

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I want to take the values if the variable I define are not equal to a particular strings. In here I want to take the values of variables 'name' , 'address' , and 'city' seperated by "-" if they are not equal to 'Tom', 'Street', and 'CityStreet' respectively. Is that possible?

```
xsl:attribute name='person'>
        <xsl:value-of separator="-" select=
    "($name, $address,
     $city)" />
        </xsl:attribute>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a predicate on your variables:

```
<xsl:attribute name='person'>
    <xsl:value-of separator="-" select="($name[.!='Tom'], $address[.!='Street'],$city[.!='CityStreet'])"/>          
</xsl:attribute>
```

or this if you don't want an empty attribute:

```
<xsl:if test="$name != 'Tom' and 
    $address != 'Street' and 
    $city != 'CityStreet'">
    <xsl:attribute name="person">
        <xsl:value-of separator="-" select="($name[.!='Tom'], $address[.!='Street'],$city[.!='CityStreet'])"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: thanks, but this works only if all three are satisfied. I want to avoid the value of one particular variable only if its not equal to the undesired string. Say if name is Tom the value of variable name should be avoided and the output should be like "someAddress-someCity".

Comment: @DevNull: The expression in the "test" attribute as currently specified is "all or nothing" while the OP wants to be able to represent any parts of the address that satisfy his conditions.

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
<xsl:if test=
  "not($name eq 'Tom' and $address eq 'Street' and $city eq 'CityStreet')">
  <xsl:attribute name="person">
    <xsl:value-of separator="-" select=
      "($name[. ne 'Tom'], $address[. ne 'Street'], $city[. ne 'CityStreet'])"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: @harsh: More importantly, the expression in the `test` attribute is correct -- unlike the one in the accepted answer, which requires all three variables to be different than the specific values -- something you have indicated isn't required.

Comment: yes of course, thanks a lot for pointing that out. Your test condition gives what I want.